How to use Stepper Motor and GP1S094HCZ0F Photointerruptor to home
I am working on a robot project and am currently working on the neck joint. For this, the head will be turning, and I am using a stepper motor for this purpose as it has more than 180 degrees of rotation and torque. I can get it to spin using the raspberry pi already.
How do I use a photointerruptor (GP1S094HCZ0F specifically) to stop and zero the motor?
I think I read the output of the sensor, and when it is high, it is home, so stop turning it, but I am unsure, it seems like these sensors are not used often in steppers anymore, at least at the hobby level.
Looking in the schematic on page 5 found at digikey under GP1S094HCZ0F, it calls for 2 resistors. I did some basic math and came up with 100 ohms for the diode line, and 150 ohms for the transistor side, but I cannot find confirmation for these numbers anywhere. This is for a 3.3V system.

Thank you for your help

when it is high, it is home ... that depends if the sensor is blocked in the home position

@jsotola my current thinking is to have it this way. When blocked, that is home position, everything is counted off of that point.

What does the datasheet say? Place a link.

@Kartman the word digikey is the link to the part page containing the latest datasheet. Thank you for looking

From discussion on VoidStar Lab's discord, a 10k resistor as a pull up resistor is desired for R1. R2 as 100 ohms is good. I have since built this circuit, had it printed and it works.
